# Visual Studio Code with VSCode Neovim extension not highlighting text in search and replace with confirm

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

I'm using Visual Studio Code (currently version 1.77.3), with the VSCode Neovim extension (version 0.0.97), which works great most of the time. But when I do a search and replace with the confirm flag, it doesn't highlight the text that will be replaced the way neovim on its own does. It doesn't even highlight the line or move the cursor to it (when I'm using %s), so the only way that I can tell that there's a match is that the arrow keys don't work.

I'm not sure if I have it configured not to, or if this is a bug.

My OS is Ubuntu jammy, and my version of neovim is v0.9.0-dev-901+g563881306.